# Azure storage lifecycle management: filtering based on file extension

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

I am using Azure Blobs to store CSV files in a container. The folder hierarchy is 3 levels deep after which CSV files are stored. The same folder structure is also used to store images.
I want to add a lifecycle management policy that deletes **only** CSV files if they are not accessed within 1 day.
I read the documentation here [Azure documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/lifecycle-management-policy-configure?tabs=azure-portal) and the only way filtering can be done is based on the prefix. Can regex be used for filtering or is there another way to configure the rule so that only CSV files are processed by the rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Azure storage lifecycle management: filtering based on file extension

The lifetime management policy in Azure Blob Storage does not directly allow standard expressions **`regex`** for object filtering, however, it does presently support filtering based on the **`prefix`**. In the lifecycle management policy, therefore, you cannot use regex to filter CSV files for deletion.

If you need to delete the CSV files, you can add [blob index tags](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-manage-find-blobs?tabs=azure-portal#setting-blob-index-tags) to all your CSV files and you can use the [Blob index filter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/lifecycle-management-overview#delete-data-with-blob-index-tags) to delete the csv files.

**Code view:**

```
{
  "rules": [
    {
      "enabled": true,
      "name": "rule2",
      "type": "Lifecycle",
      "definition": {
        "actions": {
          "baseBlob": {
            "delete": {
              "daysAfterModificationGreaterThan": 1
            }
          }
        },
        "filters": {
          "blobIndexMatch": [
            {
              "name": "sample",
              "op": "==",
              "value": "test"
            }
          ],
          "blobTypes": [
            "blockBlob"
          ],
          "prefixMatch": [
            "test"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

[image]