# Automating Deletion of Azure Blob Storage using Lifecycle Management and Filter in azure blob storage

Tags: azure-blob-storage, filtering, prefix, azure-storage-account

I've been actively working with Azure Blob Storage and its lifecycle management features. In this context, I have a Blob Storage account dedicated to storing my database backups. These backups are named using a specific convention: dbname_date_type.bak. For instance, I have blobs with names like db1_20230817_incremental.bak and db1_202030816_full.bak.

What I've already achieved is setting up a lifecycle rule that smoothly transitions these blobs from the "hot" access tier to the "cool" tier, and eventually, they're moved to the "archive" tier as they age. However, I've encountered a fresh challenge that I'm eager to resolve.

My goal is to implement an automated deletion rule. Specifically, I'm aiming to automatically delete any incremental backup blobs that remain unmodified or haven't been accessed for a continuous 60-day period.

What I've Tried:

I'm contemplating the use of the lifecycle management feature to achieve this. My thought process involves leveraging a filter and possibly setting up a blob prefix. However, I'm uncertain about the feasibility of this approach and whether it aligns with best practices.

Any insights, experiences, or guidance that you could provide would be greatly appreciated. Thank you for taking the time to read through my query.

Answer (score 0):

> My goal is to implement an automated deletion rule. Specifically, I'm aiming to automatically delete any incremental backup blobs that remain unmodified or haven't been accessed for a continuous 60-day period

To implement the automated deletion rule, you can create a **`lifecycle management policy`** with the rule that deletes blobs to meet your requirements.

Here is the sample code view to achieve the specified criteria to set up a lifecycle management policy to automatically delete incremental backup blobs that remain **`unmodified or haven't been accessed`** for a continuous 60-day period.

**Code view.**

```
{
  "rules": [
    {
      "name": "delete-incremental-backups",
      "type": "Lifecycle",
      "definition": {
        "filters": {
          "blobTypes": [
            "blockBlob"
          ],
          "prefixMatch": [
            <"Your-container-name">/<"dbname_*/incremental/>"
          ]
        },
        "actions": {
          "baseBlob": {
            "delete": {
              "daysAfterModificationGreaterThan": 60
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

[image]

Also, you can refer to my previous [SO-thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76622475/azure-storage-lifecycle-management-filtering-based-on-file-extension/76626076#76626076) to delete blob with index tags using Azure storage lifecycle management policy.

**Reference:**

[Optimize costs by automatically managing the data lifecycle - Azure Storage | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/lifecycle-management-overview?tabs=azure-powershell#lifecycle-management-rule-definition)